# How to show a custom property in design editor of Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How to show a custom property in design editor of Visual Studio?

It's with browsable option when set to true, is it right?

It isn't shown in editor... I've followed from https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

A piece of code:

```
Public Class ButtonWithBrigthness 'It inherits from Button in .Designer.vb

  Private _brigthness As Integer

  <Browsable(True)>
  Public Property Brightness() As Integer
     Get
        Return _brigthness
     End Get
     Set (value as Integer)
           _brigthness = value       
     End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? We're not here to save you having to try something simple for yourself.  We're here to help with actual problems.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is the property is not shown in design time. Obviously, I tried before I post it ;)

Comment: And are you totally 100% sure that you are using the correct DLL that actually contains the current version of your component ? You can add `Debug.Writeline("Something")` inside the constructor to check if it's the right DLL you are using. Maybe you can edit your question with you application project strucure ?

Comment: It's in the same project. I arrange it from Toolbox to form, it's a ButtonWithBrihthness object, which inherits from Button.

Comment: How exactly did you wind up with a designer code file for a class that inherits `Button`?

Comment: I just tested and your code worked fine for me.  I added a class to a WinForms app project, pasted in your code, added the `Inherits` line, built the project, added an instance to the form and opened the Properties window.  There was the `Brightness` property as expected, right at the bottom of the window in the Misc section.  It's worth noting that you don't even need that attribute because it is `True` by default and you only need it explicitly to hide a property.  If you're going to show a property to the designer then you should set a Category too.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The project had a weird error with a resource, I restarted VS and this error was solve it, and Brightness property appears too ;)